# How to write centered multi-line conclusion in inference rule?

Tags: amsmath

I'm using the semantic package to write inference rules and I have trouble with the following:

```
\usepackage[inference]{semantic}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{equation}
  \inference{ expr }{ \begin{aligned} long_expr1 \\ long_expr2 \end{aligned} }
\end{equation}
```

In this code, I want `long_expr1` and `long_expr2` to be centered. However, the aligned environment aligns them on the right. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10):

Answering my own question, the problem is solved with the *gathered* environment.

```
\begin{equation}
  \inference{ expr }{ \begin{gathered} long_expr1 \\ long_expr2 \end{gathered} }
\end{equation}
```