# How to write left aligned multi-line conclusion in inference rule?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, semantics

This question is very similar to [How to write centered multi-line conclusion in inference rule?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5964/how-to-write-centered-multi-line-conclusion-in-inference-rule). However, I can't figure out how to align an multi-line conclusion on the left. What am I missing? I'm using the `semantic` package to write inference rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inference]{semantic}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\inference{expr}{ \begin{aligned} This is a very long \\ expression \end{aligned} }
\inference{expr}{ \begin{gathered} This is a very long \\ expression \end{gathered} }

\end{document}
```

In this code, The first conclusion is aligned on the right. The second one is aligned in the middle. How can I align it on the left? Using `align` or `flalign` doesn't work and yields the following error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \begin{align} allowed only in paragraph mode.
! Package amsmath Error: \begin{flalign} allowed only in paragraph mode.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Running your given MWE I get no error or warning. I'm using the current MiKTeX 2.9 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved it by using the `array` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inference]{semantic}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\inference{expr}{ \begin{array}{l} This is a very long \\ expression \end{array} }

\end{document}
```